# cascading insert for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, insert, cascading

(After googling, reading SOF, still with the question)

Suppose we have document 'a', having an array of document 'b'. Now using the promise concept, .then(), I could possibly save to 'a' only if saving to 'b' went ok. What if saving to 'a' went wrong and I need a role back 'b'? Should I manually remove b in that case?

I may go for plugins, like mongoose-transaction-plugin (I found by searching 'transaction mongodb' on npmjs and chose what appeared as the top one). But really is it a best practice in this case please?

Comment: Not getting it. You have a document which has got an array of documents inside it and you are asking that what if the array gets inserted into DB but rest of the documents doesn't get? Is it what you are asking?

Comment: Very sorry for it's not enough clear, I'd soon post code and ask you to kindly have a look. Thank you.